# Nginx: preserve port during redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, docker

I have an Nginx server listening on `80` ran inside a Docker container.

Inside the Nginx config I need to perform a redirect to a static page in specific situations.

```
rewrite ^ /foobar.html redirect;
```

The user can run the container specifying any port using the docker command line (for reference, she can expose the container on port `8000` and internally Nginx will still use `80`).

Now, when Nginx redirects the URL, the port is replaced with the one used **internally** by Nginx instead of using the one used by Docker.

I tried to set a bunch of headers but they didn't help:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://app_server;

rewrite ^ /foobar.html redirect;
```

It still redirects to `80`.

How can I tell Nginx to preserve the port used by the user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I found a solution, I can specify the redirect as follows:

```
rewrite ^ $scheme://$http_host/foobar.html redirect;
```

This will preserve the port.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem of broken redirects inside docker by updating the Host definition in the header as defined in the nginx.conf file:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

$http_host is a lower case value of $host with the port included.

Comment: This didn't work for me.